# How can I "kill" an intent in Android java

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

The title is probably not the best but I will try to explain my problem.

I have a login/signup page where I can click on a facebook button to login through or I can click on a mail button.

When I click on this button, I open a new activity with a form to sign up. I want this activity to be transparent to a certain extent to see my first login/signup in the background page which is done. On this same page (sign up page), I have another button "I already have an account" that opens a new login activity.

This login activity is also transparent but the background is the sign up form and not my first page which is normal but I don't know how to get my first page as a background.

Any advice ?

[image]

[image]

Regards,

Arnaud

Comment: _I want this activity to be transparent to a certain extent_ why not Use Custom Dialog?

Comment: I don't know! Can I put textviews/buttons in a custom dialog ?

Comment: Apply style Theme.Dialog to your activity.

Comment: [For Example.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/) There are many other Possibilities.

Comment: My problem is not really the transparency! It is more how to manage the lifecycle of the activities.

Comment: want to kill an intent or want transparent background? Make your questions clear.

Comment: transparent which is done... so I don't want you to explain me this... Was just to set up the situation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call finish()

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `finish()` when you move to your signin page. This'll finish the signup form and the first page will show up as your background.